# Moving the Menu to the Logo Row in Joomla

Tags: templates, joomla, menu, row, graphical-logo

Im a Joomla newbie and i am looking for a solution to solve my problem. I want to moving the menu to the logo row. If im correct, there is no option to solve this problem directly from the administrator panel. After many hours spent with searching I couldn`t find a solution to that problem. Currently I use the default theme (Protostar). How can I move the menu in the same line as the logo? Thank you!

Comment: Did you change the position of the module?

Comment: After a few hours of research a did some progress. Now I have a separate module position. Used this guide to do that: [Guide](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=675&t=666848)

Right now my menubar looks like this: [Screenshot](https://p1.picsto.re/mRrqI.PNG)

[My CSS file](http://pastebin.com/JU7EDtP6)

Comment: The dropdown menu is always opened (even when the Menu is inactive). This could be a CSS problem or it is caused by the new module position? If the main menu has position-1 (navigation) the dropdown menu works just fine.
[My CSS file](http://pastebin.com/JU7EDtP6)
[Index.php file](http://pastebin.com/nirNuKp2)